# i got an error stating that === Cannot assign "'12'": "Cart.product" must be a "Product" instance. please do help me out in solving the issue

Tags: html, django

[I have attached an image of my code where you can find the add-to-cart function
and the error is on line=5][1]

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    user = request.user
    product_id = request.GET.get('prod_id')
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    Cart(user=user,product=product_id).save()
    return render(request, 'app/addtocart.html')
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: please add you code not the screenshot of you code  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You create the cart with:

```
Cart.objects.create(user=user, product_id=product_id)
```

so you assign it to `product_id`, not <s>`product`</s>, since `product=…` expects a `Product` object.

In that case you can also omit fetchting the product:

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    user = request.user
    product_id = request.GET.get('prod_id')
    Cart(user=user, product_id=product_id).save()
    return render(request, 'app/addtocart.html')
```

---

> **Note**: [*Section 9* of the *HTTP protocol*](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1)
> specifies that requests like GET and HEAD should *not* have side-effects, so you
> should not change entities with such requests. Normally POST, PUT, PATCH, and
> DELETE requests are used for this. In that case you make a small `<form>` that
> will trigger a POST request, or you use some AJAX calls.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.